# Unable to combine desktop icons into a folder on Android 7.0 Asus Zenpad 3s 10

Tags: app-icons

I have previously put an app icon over another (on this Asus Zenpad 3S 10) and a folder was created with both of them inside. Then I was able to put other icons over that folder and they also went inside of it.

However, I now am unable to combine icons into a folder. If I move an icon I want to combine into a folder over another app icon, the other app moves away. It doesn't matter how many times I move one app icon over another, the one I am hovering another app icon over, always goes quickly right or left. Is there some alternate way to combine app icons that doesn't have a bug?

Comment: @beeshyams I am using whatever launcher comes with Asus Zenpad 3S 10. I get the behavior when I am trying to combine two app icons to create a folder. You can also  get that behavior when trying to put another app icon into an already created folder, but it is not as consistently bad as with just two app icons.

Comment: @beeshyams I have "six dots"->Preferences->Folder/Icon. But I do not have anything about Show "More apps". Folder/Icon has [Folder style, Open folder animation, Folder theme, Select font, Font size, Icon label color, Icon size]

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks, that does group them all.  But I would prefer to make my own groups. I guess because most people probably don't group, this bug can hang around a long time. And it is intermittent - I was able to group some app icons.

Comment: @beeshyams I was able to do it. It has stopped letting me do it for some reason. This feature was problematic on other Android tablets/phones I have had. I have never seen it this bad though. I was able to group some icons after my initial post by swirling one icon over the other and eventually it hits some ridiculously small  sweet spot. Or maybe it is that the feature to move aside an icon to allowrearrangement,gets confused when you are swirling, allowing the feature to group to get precedence,

Comment: Thanks. Once you figure it out, you can post it to help others too :)

Answer (score 1):

Just got mine today and had the same problem. It took a bit of fidgeting, but I figured it out. Drag one of the desired icons to the static toolbar at the bottom and then drag whatever remaining icons you wish to group into that first icon. You kind of have to release immediately so it stays in that "folder" you created. This worked for me, so I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks. That does prevent the target icon from moving away as it is locked into the fixed bottom row. I had some trouble (they really need two modes) getting an initial join, as the source icon kept jumping back to its' original location when I released. After I eventually had two joined in that bottom row, I was also having trouble adding a third icon as it would also jump back to its' original location. But if you wait for the folder border to expand to release, then it worked well (add icon to already grouped icons which are in locked bottom row).